# Create-React-App network url randomly stops working?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I created a React app using create-react-app.  The issue I'm having is with being able to access it from another device on the same network.  When I deploy the app locally using "npm start", sometimes it will show the network URL and sometimes it won't.

The last time that it showed the network URL, I tried to access it from another device but it ultimately hung up with a no response.

Both devices are connected to the same network and I've tried switching between normal wifi and 5G.  No changes.

Is there a reason why it only works intermittently?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

The "On Your Network: http://172.....:3000" won't show up if there are any warnings.